# Internationalize models in Grails applications

Tags: grails, internationalization

I have a Grails application that needs internationalization. Grails makes it easy to translate fixed strings using the `messages.properties` file, but I could not find how to translate model fields.

> Is there some way to manage internationalized models, so that models in multiple languages can be entered in some admin area and the correct one will be selected in the view?

I could roll up my own system, but maybe something of this kind already exists and it is more featured and battle-tested than what I would write. This had happened to me in Django: I used a custom system - which I describe below - for internationalization, only to find out that various Django apps already solve this problem.

**An example of how to solve this issue**

If it is not clear what I am trying to achieve, here I describe the implementation I used on Django.

I had two base abstract models, `I18NModel` and `TranslationModel`. The actual models used in the application inherited from the former, while their translations from the latter. In inheriting, they needed to define a foreign key to their untranslated model and to define a field with the associated language.

The original model, in turn, inherited a method `translate`, that took a language and returned a proxy model. This proxy had a reference both to the original, untranslated model and to a translated model associated to the correct item and language.

Whenever you asked for a field on the proxy, it would try to find if it was defined on the translated model. If it was, it would return that, otherwise it would give as default the field on the untranslated model.

Hooking it with a method to find the current language, I got as a result something that I could use like this in the templates:

```
<h1>{{ article.translate.title }}</h1>
```

while allowing editors to insert translations in the admin area.

Comment: Like this? http://grails.org/plugin/i18n-fields

Comment: Thank you, it seems exactly what I was looking for! If you insert it as an answer, I will be glad to accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [i18n-fields plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/i18n-fields) does the thing.